# Most efficient way to write to file conditionally?

Tags: python

I would like to write a string to a file only if it's not presently in the file.

My first thought was to do something like this, however it's not writing anything to the file.

```
with open("FILE PATH", "a+") as database:
    for lines in database.read():
        if 'MY STRING' in lines:
            continue
        else:
            database.write('MY STRING')
```

Firstly, what am I doing wrong here? Secondly, assuming this was functioning properly, would there be a more efficient way to do this? I am assuming there is.

Thanks

Comment: `database.read()` is going to return a single string, so looping over it will iterate through every character within that string. Try using `if 'MY STRING' in database.read():` instead

Comment: If the file is empty, `.read()` returns an empty string, so the body of the for loop is never executed. As is, the code only works when the file is not empty and it's inefficient, since you always read the whole file, even if 'MY STRING' appears right at the front. Tell us what you want and how the file is supposed to be structured, because `lines` is kind of suggestive ...

Comment: @TheGirrafish your implementation worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `database.read()` will read your text file and return a single string containing the entire file. Looping over this string will return each character within that string individually, so you won't find `'MY STRING'` in it. Simply look for `'MY STRING'` within the file as a whole like so:

```py
with open("FILE PATH", "a+") as database:
    if 'MY STRING' not in database.read():
        database.write('MY STRING')
```